# How to access APIs provided by Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os

I want to use some of the APIs provided by Firefox OS. But many APIs are accessible only for privileged and certified apps. Firefox OS documentation suggests (as far as i understood) that "the apps which are deployed in marketplace are privileged apps". But how can i deploy an incomplete app to the marketplace without even testing the functionality of those APIs? Is there any other way to access those APIs? Thanks in advance

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your app using the FirefoxOS Simulator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator

Depending on the APIs you're testing the simulator can help. Some aren't available due to hardware not being available on a desktop device.

Also, if you are developing a "hosted app", you have access to APIs which use web permissions. If you need more than that you would need to create a "packaged app" with type=privileged and specify which permissions you want access to in your manifest. This is described here: https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/packaged

The app permissions table will tell you if the APIs you want required hosted, packaged, or certified (only available shipped on device).